# Calculate the numbers obtained by a die

Tags: probability, statistics

Original question:

"A fair die is rolled 150 times. Let X denote the number of sixes obtained. Use an approximation to find:

a)P(X>24)
b)P(20≤X≤25)

A.0.534 B.0.107 C.0.025 D.0.391"

I tried to use the binomial distribution transferring to normal distribution with 25 as mean and 125/6 as variance(steps shown below), but the answer didn't suit to the answer given by calculator which is about 0.534 and 0.441. I'm not pretty sure if I used the corret method. So it would be very helpful if there's any methoed I don't know can solve it.
[image: My own steps]

Edit 1:I got 0.534 and 0.441 by input these to calculator
$$1-\sum_{x=0}^{24} \binom{150}{x} \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^x \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{150-x}$$ and the output is 0.53396149.
$$\sum_{x=20}^{25} \binom{150}{x} \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^x \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{150-x}$$and the ouput is 0.4415964366.

However, there's no option about 0.587 or 0.441. But I have no idea what's the problem, especially for 0.441, because I'm using the same formula on both, but one of them is correct and another one is not.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! Take a [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour). Have a look at the [guidelines](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) on how to ask a good question.
In particular, avoid textbook-style questions - rather explain what you have tried and where specifically you need help.

Comment: Regarding the formatting of mathematical expressions: Here is a quick introduction on how to use [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: Tell us what you calculated, and how. Otherwise, how can we know where you went wrong? You must at least let us know what you think the mean and standard deviation are.

Comment: Thanks for providing more details! However, in order to avoid further downvotes, I recommend actually typing the equations - posting images containing the formulas makes them not searchable, ...

Comment: Now you computed $P(X>24)$ using the normal distribution. (a) the result is different from the one you typed in your question (b) How did you obtain the analogous result for the binomial distribution, or why are you not happy with this answer?

Comment: You should use a [continuity correction](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_correction). For example, $\Phi(0.5/\sqrt{125/6})\approx 0.544$ is now closer to your answer of $0.534$. Also your second answer is [correct](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=X~Binomial%28150%2C1%2F6%29%2C%20find%20P%2820%3C%3DX%3C%3D25%29).